# Grunt watch not working- tmp files get edited and appear

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am running `grunt watch` on my project folder which gives me following errors:

**FATAL ERROR: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'path to edited file's folder\a-temporary-file-name.tmp'**

After that is says,

Running "esteWatch" task

> > **Waiting** 
> >     **File changed: "path to edited file's folder\a-temporary-file-name.tmp"**

Running "esteWatch" task

> > **Waiting** 
> >     **File changed: "path to edited file's folder\another-temporary-file-name.tmp"**

This repeats for 5 to 6 times..

And in the end I do not get the desired result. My intended file does not get updated.

Please provide a solution.

Comment: Are you using cygwin ?

Comment: I am using git bash. With NPM.

Comment: I have installed cygwin now.

Comment: If you still have the error, try with the regular windows terminal